# Android Studio : unrecognized keystore entry + "android attributes not allowed here" in Manifest.xml

Tags: java, android

I face a new problem on Android Studio: when I want to make the project, the *Build Output* displays: "**Unrecognized keystore entry**".
More specifically an error seems to be in *Configure project* part (in the *Build Output*)

Plus, when I take a look at my *Manifest.xml* it says android attributes are not allowed here. Per example : "**Attribute android::layout_width is not allowed here**". Moreover, concerning the line "*xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"* that displays this message : "**URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas & DTDs)**"

I have already checked everything I could on the Internet... So I don't know what to do. I have already done :
- Invalidate caches/restart
- Remove .gradle et rebuild the project
- Reinstall Android Studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Almost every line is red in color. How can I fix this issue? I specify that I didn't edit anything. I just created a new project and anything else.

EDIT : in the log the first issue I see is a ProjectConfigurationException. So I show you my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dorian.mykotlinapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

It happens in every projects I create

Answer (score 1):

"Unrecognized keystore entry" likely means the `signingConfig` does not match any key.

and remove these lines:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
```

these are the most common name-spaces:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

after building the project once, not every other line should be red.

Comment: After removing these two lines, the issue isn't resolved. If the name-space is "**xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android**" it's right no ?

Comment: try to update like this xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"